# How to make a post request to redis server

Tags: node.js, post, redis

How do we make a POST request from NODE Js to Redis server and POLL the messages back from some other NODE JS server.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) or [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis)